# How to retrive data from 'select2' type multiple field in Drupal 8

Tags: forms, jquery-select2, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I guess my problem might be trivial one but still i cannot find any answer on the internet so i would be glad for any hint.

As in the topic I am building a Form in Drupal 8. Everything was working but i decided to switch checkboxes FormElement to Select2. The field is supposed to be of multiple choice character.

My question is **how to retrive this data after Form Submit**? I tried many things but the best i get after `$form_state->getValue('field')`  is the last of the chosen values - not all. And i need all chosen by the user values to get them and then convert intro string.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using module [Select2](https://www.drupal.org/project/select2), otherwise you should use it.

I built a test form with a `select2` field allowing multiple selections. When the form is submited, `$form_state->getValue('field')` gives an array of keys of the selected options. You can use it to get their corresponding values like this:

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\test\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Class TestForm.
 */
class TestForm extends FormBase {

  protected $options =  [
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3'
  ];

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'test_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['field'] = [
      '#type' => 'select2',
      '#title' => t('Test field'),
      '#options' => $this->options,
      '#multiple' => TRUE,
    ];

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $selected_keys = $form_state->getValue('field');
    $selected_values = array_intersect_key($this->options, $selected_keys);
    print_r($selected_values); 
    die;  // just to see debug result
  }

}
```